# GPUImage: GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlur apply to large size image will black in the area being excluded blur

Tags: gpuimage

I am trying to apply GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter to GPUImagePicture. But there seems to have a problem.

Initial GPUImagePicture with "[[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:image smoothlyScaleOutput:NO]". And,when the image size is larger (maybe width > 1024px ),the area being excluded from the blur on the image  may become black whiteout anything (define by excludeCircleRadius property in GPUImageGaussianSelectiveBlurFilter)!

This problem will without exist if I smaller the image size (example: 640 * 960 px).

Could somebody tell me what may cause this problem please? Thank you very much!Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I seems to solve the problem. The key is that GPUImagePicture will get conserveMemoryForNextFrame use  "if (MAX(pixelSizeOfImage.width, pixelSizeOfImage.height) > 1000.0)" This mean that the image can not be over 1000px size.